# How to disable all tabs on JTabbedPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

This is actually a 2 part question.

1. If the first tab is disabled and a Button exists, it will still work. The user must click off the tab to see that it is disabled.
2. Is it possible to disable all tabs?

Here is the test code.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class JTabbedPanel  {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Devices");
      JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
      JTextArea text = new JTextArea(100,100);
      JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3;
      JButton button1 = new JButton("Press Me");
      button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            System.out.println("It still works");
        }
 
      });
      panel1 = new JPanel();
      panel1.add(button1);
      panel2 = new JPanel();
      panel2.add(text);
      panel3 = new JPanel();
      tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
      tabbedPane.setForeground(Color.black);
      tabbedPane.addTab("Laptop", panel1);
      tabbedPane.addTab("Desktop ", panel2);
      tabbedPane.addTab("Notebook", panel3);
      tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(0, false);
      tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(2, false);
      frame.add(tabbedPane);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setSize(550,350);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

***Test 1 :***

Run the code "as is" and the first and third tab is disabled with a button. When the dialog appears, the button can still be pressed on the first tab. The second tab is enabled. Click the 2nd tab and now the use can not access the first tab as expected.

***Question 1:***
Is it up to the user to track which tabs are disabled and then set the default tab via `tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(1);` to one which is enabled?

***Test 2 :***

Add the following line of code. Now all tabs are disabled.

```
tabbedPane.setEnabledAt(1, false);
```

Now that all tabs are disabled, it will still default to the first tab and still have the button enabled.

***Question 2:***

In a scenario in which all tabs are disabled for what ever reason, how is it best to handle this? I was expecting to see all components on the tab to be disabled, but that would have to be done manually.

Comment: (1) As far as I know yes, there is no other way. The default tab that is selected is the first one and if you don't want it to be, you have to make sure to change it. (2) Disabling the tab does not disable the components the current tab is displaying. You are only disabling the selection of the tab in the TabbedPane.

Comment: Why are you showing tabbed panels that the user cannot access (disabled)?  That's not a good user experience.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I don’t know that I would agree with that in every case.  Often it’s better if the user can see what functionality is available, since the user can’t know to use or activate things they’ve never seen.

Comment: @VGR: I generally agree.  That's why I asked a question.  In my experience, it's better to hide functionality that can never be used by that access level.

Comment: There could be multiple tabs and at any given moment one or more tabs (or all) could be disabled due to certain data criteria. With regards to user experience, in this scenario, it is better to show all tabs disabled instead of the user seeing all tabs one day and the entire panel gone the next. That type of inconsistency is worse than showing disabled tabs.